# Python pandas replace string at specific location inside string

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, slice

I would like to ask for a little help.

I have a frame consisting of multiple columns, here in this case I just highlighted three columns, which are important for me

`frame=pd.DataFrame({"String":["000111222f12","000121222f11","000131222f12","000141222f12"],"Cavity":  ["Cav 2", "Cav 1", "Cav 1", "Cav 2"]})`

```
   Cavity     String  
0  Cav 2  011121222f12              
1  Cav 1  011111222f14              
2  Cav 2  011111222f16              
3  Cav 2  000111222f17
```

What I would like to get is the following: Based on cavity column, I need to change the 4.location (counting at zero) for the string, meaning if I have Cav 2 I should have 0111**2**1222f16

The desired solution should look like this

```
   Cavity     String      Corrected String
0  Cav 2  011121222f12    011121222f12            
1  Cav 1  011111222f14    011111222f14            
2  Cav 2  011111222f16    011121222f16            
3  Cav 2  000111222f17    000121222f17
```

I tried to solve it with a combination of replace and slicing the string at the specific location and using np.where, but without success.

Any advice for me?

Cheers and thanks

Comment: Is necessary extract number and use for correct data? Or only replace `Cav 2` to `2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
frame['Corrected String'] = frame['String'].str[:4] + frame['Cavity'].str.split().str[-1] + frame['String'].str[5:]
```

Comment: thanks mate exactly what I was looking for. Solved it by a work around but this is defintley the solution I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way. You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute the string between 2 capture groups:

```
import re

frame['Corrected_String'] = [re.sub(r'^(.{4}).(.*)$', fr'\g<1>{c[-1]}\g<2>', s)
                             for s, c in zip(frame['String'], frame['Cavity'])]
```

[out]

```
         String Cavity Corrected_String
0  000111222f12  Cav 2     000121222f12
1  000121222f11  Cav 1     000111222f11
2  000131222f12  Cav 1     000111222f12
3  000141222f12  Cav 2     000121222f12
```

---

#### Explanation

the `pattern` parameter here is the regex pattern `'^(.{4}).(.*)$'`.

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- `(.{4})` - this is the first capture group (`\g<1>`), denoting the first 4 characters of the string.
- `.` - this is the fifth character in the string, ultimately the character that we'll replace.
- `(.*)$` - this is the 2nd capture group (`\g<2>`), denoting all remaining characters up to the end of the string (`$`)

the `repl` parameter here is the replacement string `fr'\g<1>{c[-1]}\g<2>'`.

- `\g<1>` the first capture group (first 4 characters)
- Since we're using f-string notation, `{c[-1]}` will be evaluated as the last character of the `Cavity` value.
- `\g<2>` - the 2nd capture group (all remaining characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract integer from `Cavity` column and add after `4.position`:

```
s = frame['Cavity'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
frame['Corrected'] = frame['String'].str[:4] + s + frame['String'].str[5:]
print (frame)
         String Cavity     Corrected
0  000111222f12  Cav 2  000121222f12
1  000121222f11  Cav 1  000111222f11
2  000131222f12  Cav 1  000111222f12
3  000141222f12  Cav 2  000121222f12
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way:

```
import pandas as pd
frame=pd.DataFrame({"String":["000111222f12","000121222f11","000131222f12","000141222f12"],"Cavity":  ["Cav 2", "Cav 1", "Cav 1", "Cav 2"]})
frame['Corrected'] = frame['String'].str[:4] + frame['Cavity'].str.strip('Cav ') + frame['String'].str[5:]
print(frame)
```

Output:

```
         String Cavity     Corrected
0  000111222f12  Cav 2  000121222f12
1  000121222f11  Cav 1  000111222f11
2  000131222f12  Cav 1  000111222f12
3  000141222f12  Cav 2  000121222f12
```

Answer (score 0):

not faster but maybe clearer and reusable

```
def replace_nth_char(chaine: str, pos: int, value: str) -> str:
    """replace character in string at given position"""
    a = list(chaine)
    a[pos] = value
    return "".join(a)


frame.loc[:, "Corrected"] = frame.apply(lambda row: replace_nth_char(row["String"], 4, row["Cavity"][-1]), axis=1)
```